# Creating a new barplot showing the number of times a Themes is showing. Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart

so i have a vector with Themes for example:
Gore, Military, Survival
Parody, Super Power
Love Polygon, Video Game

I want to create a barplot showing the number of times each Themes is showing.
I used: dummy_cols(Alldata2, select_columns = "Themes",split=",")
This create a matrix and not sure how can I barplot it

I used the code above to create the dummies however not sure hot can I barplot for all Themes.
The list has  24,000 lines and according to the dummies a total of 52 Themes.
[Themes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOiXH.png)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create a dummy matrix. Using `ggplot2` you could get a basic barchart of the counts using a `geom_bar` like so:

```r
set.seed(123)

Alldata2 <- data.frame(
  Themes = sample(c("Gore", "Military", "Survival Parody", "Super Power Love Polygon", "Video Game"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Alldata2, aes(x = Themes)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

**UPDATE** One option to split your strings would be to use `tidyr::separate_rows`:

```r
set.seed(123)

Alldata2 <- data.frame(
  Themes = sample(c(
    "Gore, Militar, Love", "War, Magical, Love",
    "Survival Parody", "Super Power Love Polygon", "Video Game"
  ), 100, replace = TRUE)
)

Alldata2 <- tidyr::separate_rows(Alldata2, Themes, sep = ", ")

ggplot(Alldata2, aes(x = Themes)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry it did not show as I wanted each data has more than one Theme, something like this:
`c("Gore, Militar, Love", "War, Magical, Love","Survival Parody")`

So the first step should be separate them which is why the dummy matrix and then count them however I am not sure how to do that. Thanks

Comment: Hi Diego. Not a big deal. See my update on one option to split your vector in a vector of single themes.

Answer (score 0):

Until some weeks ago (before ggplot2 3.4.0   2022/11/07) `qplot` would have been an alternative, [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/ggplot2-3-4-0/):

Note: `qplot`  was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
Data taken from @stefan (many thanks!)

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x=Themes, data = Alldata2)
```

[image]